# PerformSelector Monotouch Threading

Tags: multithreading, css-selectors, timer, xamarin.ios

Using this statement calls the selector immediately instead of 6 seconds from now.

```
this.PerformSelector(myStartWaitForSoundSelector, null, 6.0f);
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work with a delay?

I am using `thread.Sleep(6000)`in the function that gets called, but the entire application locks up for six seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an NSTimer:

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6),
                    delegate { Console.WriteLine("teste"); });
```

That will cause the code inside the delegate to run after 6 seconds, without blocking the main application thread.